# scrapy: Can I extract request formdata from response?

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape some data, I am wondering how much data of *Request* the *Response* stores.

My specific question is shown in the following code:

```
def parse(self,response):
    r = FormRequest(url=url1, formdata={somedata}, callback=parse2)

    #is this line necessary if I want the formdata being attached?
    r.meta['formdata'] = formdata

    yield r

def parse2(self,response):
    #can I access to the formdata here without that line of code?
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, however `formdata` is already converted into `body` and won't be the dictionary but a string as far as I remember.

so try `r.body` also quick reminder you can check the attributes of an object by:
`dir(r)`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You are right, I can find the formdata as a string like 'key1=v1&key2=v2' in the response.request.body. However, I need this two features as the formdata of the later request, do you know how I can use it without extraction of the string(split and put in a new dict) or using request.meta?

Comment: You can just put the `formdata` to `request.meta` when creating the `FormRequest` object i.e. `FormRequest(url, formdata=fd, callback=parse2, meta={'formdata': fd}` and then you can access it in `parse2` by `response.meta['formdata']`